# How to smooth and seal the raw garage stairs?

Tags: garage, stairs

I have a couple of raw wood garage steps. How can I  smooth and seal them, because some of the wood at the edges is splintering, and the rings are rough as well. The wood stairs themselves are relatively smooth otherwise. Is this something you just stain and seal? Or would you leave it and install some finished stair treads on top? I'm not that particular about how it ends up looking.

[image: Raw garage stairs]

Comment: Your question asks for opinions, which makes it off topic. We're not a discussion forum or polling platform. Please see the [help] and take the [tour].

Comment: I have edited it to not ask for opinions.  If you don't like the edit, you may reverse it.

Answer (score 1):

Step one would be to measure them and make sure the riser height is consistent. Might be the picture angle but it looks like that might not be the case.

If not, correct that first. Depending on how it's out of whack, if it is, covering with nicer wood (thick-ish, to a precise height) can be one approach. Inconsistent riser height can cause falls.

If of consistent height or corrected to consistent height, you could paint, or use some sort of overlay (thin) such as rubber treads (and risers, if you like) for more traction and a consistent appearance.

Given not caring much how it looks, sealing them with floor paint of some sort is probably the right level of effort, since they typically will get wet with foot traffic when it rains. Consider adding some traction aid (often more-or-less sand) to the paint on top of the treads.

I'd also mask off the stairs and fill the drywall gaps around them, as that's sloppy, but cutting the fancy trim board to go there is a lot of effort for a stair of limited appearance aspirations.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  

The risers are mostly even - just a bad picture on my part - the first two stairs are 7.5", although the final step up to the door is 8".  

When you say you'd "mask off the stairs" - what does that mean? Is that just putting masking tape around the edges so when you fill it, it doesn't get on the stairs?

Comment: Yup - strip of tape on the stairs so you can shove drywall joint compound into the gap without getting it all over the stairs. A 1/8" overlay (1st step) and a 1/4" overlay (2nd step) would even out your step height. More than 3/8" variance is against code, as is a riser height over 7-3/4"

Comment: Technically you want the _rise_ height consistent, not riser height. Tread thickness can vary (as it does with this threshold), and therefore the riser height would change.

Comment: Code language is clear that the "riser" they refer to is between treads. e.g. R311.7.5.1 "*The riser shall be measured vertically between leading edges of the adjacent treads.*"

Comment: The overlay suggestion is really helpful, thank you. FWIW - looks like the treads are about 1", the riser for the first two steps then are 6", and the final step up to the metal piece is about 7.25" or so.

Comment: If you put the end of a tape measure on the concrete floor what is the reading at the top front of the first step? If you put the end of a tape measure on the top of the 1st step at the edge of the 2nd step, what is the reading at the top front of the 2nd step? If you put a the end of a tape measure on the top of the 2nd step at the edge of the threshold, what is the reading on the thtreshold? Very likely these will work out so that if you put 1/2" of finish material on each of the two treads then the three riser measurements will be equal within requirements, but do the measuring and report.

Comment: Possible tread covering https://www.americanfloormats.com/round-coin-rubber-stair-treads/?gclid=CjwKCAiApuCrBhAuEiwA8VJ6JhEj9oOKRUSMJ5Vd1kl7Xq5YzzhFh_ygB-336mEwHhsgwHQzU9j2KBoCwuoQAvD_BwE   https://kofflersales.com/product/stair-treads-safety-rib-by-roppe?itemid=19759&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=PMax%3A%20%28ROI%29%20Shopping%20-%20Smart%20-%20High%20AOV%20%28updated%29&utm_id=17809292308&utm_content=&utm_term=&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiApuCrBhAuEiwA8VJ6JkulWZo-r0vN7z94EvBDm5ZxM_GRSxEFnW22dylyfcLYruaGmEaPARoCz34QAvD_BwE